# How to filter an array of object using a dynamic object?

Tags: javascript

I have this array of object:

```
  data = [
          {
            delivered: 118989,
            sent: 132288,
            undelivered: 13299,
            _id: {
              broker: "123",
              campaign: "notificacao1",
              category: "teste",
              event_code: "21295",
              priority: "HIGH",
            }
          },
          {
            delivered: 27,
            sent: 35,
            undelivered: 8,
            _id: {
              broker: "555",
              campaign: null,
              category: "teste",
              event_code: "4494",
              priority: "HIGH",
            }
          }
        ]
```

and I have an Object witch can be dynamic, with one or more property, like this:

```
 filterForm = {
      broker: "123",
    }
```

or

```
 filterForm = {
    broker: "123"
    priority: "HIGH"
    }
```

I want to filter the array of object, using the result of the second dynamic object.

> Note that I need to filter inside the property _id

I tried using filter.

```
this.data = this.data.filter(function (item) {
      for (var key in filterForm) {
        if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != filterForm[key])
          return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
```

but I always get false

Comment: There's no `prioridade`. Where's the mapping that defines which property of the _"dynamic object"_ matches which property in the input? Have all properties to be equal, or one, or two, ...?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: there was a problem with my translation, english is not my first language, I already edited the question.

Comment: So every property of that _"dynamic object"_ has to match with its "sibling" in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `filter` function filtering array by using a loop on dynamic object (in my example is called `filterObj`):

```js
let myArray = [ { delivered: 118989, sent: 132288, undelivered: 13299, _id: { broker: "123", campaign: "notificacao1", category: "teste", event_code: "21295", priority: "HIGH", } }, { delivered: 27, sent: 35, undelivered: 8, _id: { broker: "555", campaign: null, category: "teste", event_code: "4494", priority: "HIGH", } } ];
    
let filterObj = {broker: "123", priority: "HIGH"};

let result = myArray.filter(el => {
   for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filterObj)) {
      return el._id[key] === value;
   }
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.data = this.data.filter((item) => Object
   .entries(filterForm)
   .every(([key, value]) => item._id[key] === value)
);
```